# Difference of sets of multiple values for single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, set

I've got some grouped tabular data, and in this data there's a column for which each data point can actually have a set of different values. I'm trying to calculate the difference of that set from that of its preceding data point in the group it's a member of. For example, given the data below, I'm trying to calculate the difference of the values of `Tokens`<sup>†</sup> for `Timestep` value *n* from the values of `Tokens` for the row with `Timestamp` value *n* - 1 for each `Dyad,Participant` combination:

```
| Dyad | Participant | Timestep | Tokens            |
|------|-------------|----------|-------------------|
| 1    | A           | 1        | apple,banana      |
| 1    | B           | 1        | apple,orange      |
| 1    | A           | 2        | banana            |
| 1    | B           | 2        | orange,kumquat    |
| 1    | A           | 3        | orange            |
| 1    | B           | 3        | orange,pear       |
| 2    | A           | 1        | orange,pear       |
| 2    | B           | 1        | apple,banana,pear |
| 2    | A           | 2        | banana,persimmon  |
| 2    | B           | 2        | apple             |
| 2    | A           | 3        | banana            |
| 2    | B           | 3        | apple             |
```

How can I best accomplish this using pandas?

### Expected result

I ultimately want to create a new column with the output of a function `token_overlap(data)` which computes the ratio of `Token` values that overlap with the values of the datapoint preceding it:

```
| Dyad | Participant | Timestep | Tokens            | TokenOverlap |
|------|-------------|----------|-------------------| -------------|
| 1    | A           | 1        | apple,banana      | (no value)   |
| 1    | B           | 1        | apple,orange      | (no value)   |
| 1    | A           | 2        | banana            | 0.5          |
| 1    | B           | 2        | orange,kumquat    | 0.333        |
| 1    | A           | 3        | orange            | 0            |
| 1    | B           | 3        | orange,pear       | 0.333        |            
| 2    | A           | 1        | orange,pear       | (no value)   |
| 2    | B           | 1        | apple,banana,pear | (no value)   |
| 2    | A           | 2        | banana,persimmon  | 0            |
| 2    | B           | 2        | apple             | 0.333        |
| 2    | A           | 3        | banana            | 0.5          |
| 2    | B           | 3        | apple             | 1            |
```

### Current approach

I convert the multi-values into a `frozenset` by using the `converters` keyword of [`pandas.read_csv(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
def parse_set(cell_value: str) -> FrozenSet[str]:
    return frozenset(cell_value.split(','))

round_tokens = pandas.read_csv(inpath, converters={"Tokens": parse_set})
```

I then create groups of `Dyad,Participant` datapoints using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby(..)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
round_tokens.sort_values(["Dyad", "Timestep"])
dyad_participants = round_tokens.groupby(["Dyad", "Participant"])
```

However, I am unsure how to get each row and it's precedessor's `Tokens` value (which should be a `frozenset`): I have some function which tries to do so but I'm unsure if the function itself is wrong or if I'm extracting the row data incorrectly.

```
def token_overlap(data):
    own_relevant_tokens = data["Tokens"]
    prev_tokens = data.shift(-1)["Tokens"]
    overlap = own_relevant_tokens.intersection(prev_tokens)
    union = own_relevant_tokens.union(prev_tokens)
    return len(overlap) / len(union)

round_tokens["TokenOverlap"] = dyad_participants.apply(token_overlap)
```

However, this doesn't actually work: The actual error is

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'union'

but I know I'm not using/understanding/grokking the pandas API correctly, hence the extremely long-winded question. **How can I group my data and then, inside each group, calculate a metric using set-like values from one row and the same column's values for the row preceding it?**

---

<sup>†</sup>In the real data, there are over 1,000 possible values for `Tokens`, so, at least to me, this task would be even harder if I enumerated the presence of each token as Boolean values, e.g. `Token_Apple`, `Token_Banana`, etc.

Comment: Could you please add your expected output for your sample?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ done. Does that help?

Comment: yes. I understood more from that output than I did reading all your text. ;-) So if a group has only one element, the output is (no value)?

Comment: No, it only has no value if there is no timestep preceding it; I added some extra datapoints to illustrate that.

Comment: Ahhhh, you've changed your output again. But I've solved it, so give me a few.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to prettify it; The actual values shouldn't be different (assuming that what I'm trying to do was understood)

Comment: Okay, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df
    Dyad Participant  Timestep             Tokens
0      1           A         1       apple,banana
1      1           B         1       apple,orange
2      1           A         2             banana
3      1           B         2     orange,kumquat
4      1           A         3             orange
5      1           B         3        orange,pear
6      2           A         1        orange,pear
7      2           B         1  apple,banana,pear
8      2           A         2   banana,persimmon
9      2           B         2              apple
10     2           A         3             banana
11     2           B         3              apple

tokens = df.Tokens.str.split(',', expand=False).apply(frozenset) 

tokens
0           (apple, banana)
1           (orange, apple)
2                  (banana)
3         (orange, kumquat)
4                  (orange)
5            (orange, pear)
6            (orange, pear)
7     (apple, banana, pear)
8       (persimmon, banana)
9                   (apple)
10                 (banana)
11                  (apple)
Name: Tokens, dtype: object
```

---

```
# union logic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46402781/4909087
df =  df.assign(Tokens=tokens)\
        .groupby(['Dyad', 'Participant']).apply(\
               lambda x: (x.Tokens.str.len() - 
                      x.Tokens.diff().str.len()) \
                    / pd.Series([len(k[0].union(k[1])) 
   for k in zip(x.Tokens, x.Tokens.shift(1).fillna(''))], index=x.index))\
        .reset_index(level=[0, 1], name='TokenOverlap')\
        .assign(Timestep=df.Timestep, Tokens=df.Tokens)\
        .sort_values(['Dyad', 'Timestep', 'Participant'])\
        .fillna('(no value)')\
         [['Dyad', 'Participant', 'Timestep', 'Tokens', 'TokenOverlap']]

df

    Dyad Participant  Timestep             Tokens TokenOverlap
0      1           A         1       apple,banana   (no value)
1      1           B         1       apple,orange   (no value)
2      1           A         2             banana          0.5
3      1           B         2     orange,kumquat     0.333333
4      1           A         3             orange            0
5      1           B         3        orange,pear     0.333333
6      2           A         1        orange,pear   (no value)
7      2           B         1  apple,banana,pear   (no value)
8      2           A         2   banana,persimmon            0
9      2           B         2              apple     0.333333
10     2           A         3             banana          0.5
11     2           B         3              apple            1
```

In a nutshell, what this code is doing is, grouping by `Dyad` and `Participant`, and then finding pairwise ratio. This needs some complicated `groupby` and `apply`, since we need to do a few set `union` and `difference` operations. The The core logic is inside the `groupby.apply`, while the rest is just prettification.

This code runs in:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop
```

---

**Breakdown**

```
df2 = df.assign(Tokens=tokens)
df2 = df2.groupby(['Dyad', 'Participant']).apply(\
                   lambda x: (x.Tokens.str.len() - 
                          x.Tokens.diff().str.len()) \
                        / pd.Series([len(k[0].union(k[1])) 
       for k in zip(x.Tokens, x.Tokens.shift(1).fillna(''))], index=x.index)) # the for loop is part of this huge line

df2 = df2.reset_index(level=[0, 1], name='TokenOverlap')    
df2 = df2.assign(Timestep=df.Timestep, Tokens=df.Tokens)
df2 = df2.sort_values(['Dyad', 'Timestep', 'Participant']).fillna('(no value)')    
df2 = df2[['Dyad', 'Participant', 'Timestep', 'Tokens', 'TokenOverlap']]
```

Comment: ended up here because of your other question, well done, but realistically, how the hell is anyone supposed to understand that lengthy one-liner?

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution isn't working (at least for my real data), failing at `.str.split(',', expand=False).apply(frozenset)` because of `line 2355, in apply mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66645) TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Pandas is doing too much magic for me to understand what that means; I set `dtype` for `read_csv` for the column to `str`and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @errantlinguist It looks like your "Tokens" column is not really a column of comma separated strings. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how useful this solution is going to be for you anymore.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, I had originally forced it to being a `frozenset`, but if I don't forcibly convert it, I have no idea what pandas turns it into before it hits your code.

Comment: @errantlinguist Substitute that line of code with whatever it takes to get your thing into a frozenset. It should still work. I presume you can handle it since you took it upon yourself to be able to convert an MCVE solution to one that can fit your actual data.

Comment: Okay, I was confused because of the string operations like `x.Tokens.str.len()`. Still, I'm having trouble with index lookup; Is there no way to do it for cases where `Tokens` is not in the index?

Comment: Can you explain? `Tokens` is not a part of the index anywhere.

Comment: I'm getting a `KeyError: "['Tokens'] not in index"` at the line equivalent to your `[['Dyad', 'Participant', 'Timestep', 'Tokens', 'TokenOverlap']]` and, once again, have no idea why or even where to start looking... (I feel stupid that debugging C++ code makes more sense to me, hence mentioning that I don't "grok" pandas)

Comment: @errantlinguist Did you not run this line? `.assign(Timestep=df.Timestep, Tokens=df.Tokens)`. it should add the column after the groupby.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that. However, after adding my version of `df.assign(Tokens=tokens)` I still get the same error (in my code, `tokens = df.Tokens` because I had to convert `Tokens` using a converter instead of what you did, hence leaving it out because it looks unnecessary)

Comment: `df.assign` is not inplace... You need `df = df.assign(Tokens=tokens)`..

Comment: Yes, my code has `df.assign(Tokens=tokens).groupby(...)`, not a separate statement.

Comment: @errantlinguist You must assign again after the groupby, because it disappears.

Comment: Then it seems I simply don't understand pandas enough to ask about it on SO because I only see one `assign(...)` statement in your code using `tokens`.

Comment: @errantlinguist What!! Look right after the `reset_index` call... there's yet another one there.

Comment: Then the indentation got messed up during copying and the whole thing is way too complicated for me to deduce the correct indentation myself: The last parenthesis in `pd.Series([len(k[0].union(k[1]))` is matching up to that in `apply(\ ` according to my editor, thus I thought the `for k in ... ` came after `df = df.assign(...)`

Comment: @errantlinguist Did you get it now or do you want me to rewrite it?

Comment: You can do if you want, but if I try to add a parenthesis after the giant `for` thing then there's a syntax error, so I believe I translated the code correctly but for whatever reason it doesn't work for my data. I should probably have done this all by myself in Java instead of using pandas.

Comment: @errantlinguist edited, does that help? (java would've been worse, probably)

Comment: @errantlinguist That is perfectly valid. It was my mistake when translating it. Find my edit, I've removed the "inplace" and assigned the return back.

Comment: It now works and is also more or less understandable to me. Thanks a bajillion for the extreme level of help.

Comment: @errantlinguist Fantastic, thanks for your patience with pandas.